# how to increase disk size on centos

Tags: centos, virtualbox

My disk on virtual box was to small, so I made it bigger with VBoxManage and assigned the new, free space to the main partition afterwards using gparted. But working with the system I still get errors kind of 'no disk space available'
What is missing?

fdisk -l shows that disk /dev/sda has 14 GB. That's new size.

```
[root@office data]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 14.0 GB, 13991149568 bytes, 27326464 sectors
Units = Sektoren of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000a2e1f

   Gerät  boot.     Anfang        Ende     Blöcke   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048    27326463    13150208   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 7159 MB, 7159676928 bytes, 13983744 sectors
Units = Sektoren of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 859 MB, 859832320 bytes, 1679360 sectors
Units = Sektoren of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

but df -h does not show the new size on /centos-root. Instead there are some tmpfs entries that I don't understand. How can I assign the new diskspace to my "working" partition?

```
[root@office data]# df -h
Dateisystem             Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
/dev/mapper/centos-root  6,7G    6,7G   16K  100% /
devtmpfs                 1,9G       0  1,9G    0% /dev
tmpfs                    1,9G       0  1,9G    0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1,9G    8,6M  1,9G    1% /run
tmpfs                    1,9G       0  1,9G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                497M    206M  292M   42% /boot
tmpfs                    379M       0  379M    0% /run/user/0
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer myself, explained [here](https://community.webcore.cloud/tutorials/linux_specific_articles/how_to_extend_partition_with_unallocated_space_cen/):

So the Steps to enlarge your virtualbox disk for a centos guest are:

1. Use VBoxManage utility to resize the disk
2. Use GParted to assign the new unallocated space
3. And the Step I was missing: Use the description from the link to
   manage the disk within centos

Comment: Step 2 is explained in great details in the second part of [this page](https://nagios.force.com/support/s/article/Resizing-The-VM-Disk-Size-For-CentOS-7-f76c1dc6). Helped a lot to assign the new space

Answer (score -1):

Your disks are using logical volume mapping (LVM) because "mapper" is in the dev names. The best way can doesn't require gparted or messing with your files. Refer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/659099/352647

Comment: The best course of action is to avoid using gparted? Why? I'm not saying you're wrong. "The best way can avoid" is not easy to understand. It's bad grammar.

Comment: @mr-zog The whole point of using logical volume mapping is not to physically alter the volumes they're composed of. Just create an extra partition and add it to the logical volume, your existing data is untouched/safe. I've edited my answer. Sure, you could try gparted if you want for part of the process, but all the internet tutorials about resizing partitions shouldn't be followed.